# Is it possible to disable the light-blue mouse over highlighting on a QTreeWidgetItem?

Tags: c++, qt, signals, qtreewidget

I've a QTreeWidget and need to disable the mouse over highlighting on the childItems but not the click selection. The point here is, that I need to set this per Item because some are selectable. I was thinking about the `QTreeWidget::itemEntered` signal to check if the item should be highlighted or not but I can't get it to work because the description says

> QTreeWidget mouse tracking needs to be enabled for this feature to
>   work.

and I can't figure out how.

So my questions for are: How can I enable mouse tracking?

Is there an easier way to disable the highlighting?

Comment: Not sure about easier, but standard way here is to write a delegate.

Comment: Well @MarcoA. It seems i just missed that one xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply invoke [setMouseTracking()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop) to enable mouse tracking for a specific widget.

Comment: do you know how to disable the highlighting too? Is there a flag, an event or something?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23111163/1938163) might be a good starting point since it's a styling problem

Comment: Yeah i thought about stylesheet but that wont work because it's for all items QTableView::item. It's not possible to set stylesheet per item so i need another way for this =(

Comment: Not sure I got it correctly, what about the focus selector? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24819698/1938163

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem (I know this is an old post, but I might as well post my solution, since it can be useful for others).

I could not properly disable the mouse feedback while keeping the mouse tracking enabled, but I could make this feedback invisible. I'm using qss stylesheets, and I set the mousehover feedback color to transparent:

```
MyTreeWidget::item:hover {
    background-color: transparent
}
```

It did the trick for me. Sadly it makes the feedback invisible all the time, rather than allowing to turn it off and on.

So as a next step, for when I needed it, I implemented my own feedback by using a delegate and overwritting the `paint` function.
The QTreeView overwrite `mouseMoveEvent` and sends mouse coordinates to the delegate. This way, the delegate can adapt what it does in `paint` to this position. It feels pretty heavy, and a bit dirty, but it works. Delegate should also allow to have different behavior for different items.

PS: If you're using a delegate, in most cases, that should be enough without the qss change. In my case it wasn't, because I call `QStyledItemDelegate::paint` in my overwritten `paint` method, so I inherited some unwanted behavior.